# List applied discounts that have codes

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, discounts

So on a cart page, I need to list out the discounts that have been applied to a cart. I need to list them one by one, but only discounts that are applied with a code. I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the discount code, and I need to output the code. Something like this:

```
Item Total: $200.00
Promotional (25OFF): -$25.00
Promotional (FATHERSDAY): -$10.00
...
```

I'm looking over the discount info like this:

```
{% for discount in cart.adjustments %}
    {{ dump(discount) }}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

I don't see an accessible code variable jumping out at me. The only places I can see pulling it is from the `optionsJson` string, but that is not practical as Twig doesn't have a default JSON filter to decode.

So I can get the discount ID easily enough from that loop; but I'm not sure how to pull a Discount model based on ID. I'm not super versed with Craft and Twig, so I'm hoping there is a simple solution to look up Discounts based on discount ID.

So like this:

```
{% for discounts in cart.adjustments %}
    {# look up discount based on discount.id #}
        {% if discount.code | length %}
            Promotional ({{ discount.code }}): {# discount amount, probably have to do math here if it is a percentage #}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I imagine I'm going about this wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(There can be only one code on a cart at any one time)

Here's some example code that does the sort of thing you want:

```
{% if cart.couponCode %}
    {% set coupon = craft.commerce.getDiscountByCode(cart.couponCode) %}
{% endif %}

{% if cart.totalDiscount or coupon is not null %}

    {% for adjustment in cart.adjustments if adjustment.type == "Discount" %}
        {% set isCoupon = adjustment.optionsJson.code ? true : false %}                

    <strong>Applied: </strong>

        {% if isCoupon %}                
            <div class="coupon-item">
                <div class="clear">
                    <div class="cartSection__text">

                        Coupon: <strong>{{ adjustment.optionsJson.code }}</strong>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="cartSection__description">
                    {{ adjustment.description }}
                </div>
            </div>
            {% set couponPrinted = true %}
        {% else % }
            etc...
```

Comment: Goddamnit, I thought I tried that. I think I was just accessing the `optionsJson` code array node on the wrong parent. Thank you! Worked exactly as needed.